# Install Python packages in dataflow job

Tags: python, dataflow

In my dataflow (beam) workflow I use the datetime package from Python (using jupyter notebook on gcp). Everything works fine when I install missing packages with pip.

Now I would like to run my transformation as dataflow job on gcp.

I always get the mistake "NAME ERROR" because datetime is not known (get this mistake when I use Apache beam SDK for Python) Can anyone give me a hint how to add Python packages to a dataflow job?

I was using a setup.py file but it doesn't work.

Comment: I use a setup.py file for this, which works for me.  Can you add the command that you use to run dataflow and the setup.py file which does not work for you.

Comment: Also, is `datetime`the only import which is failing?  If so, this isn't a python package error as [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) is part of the standard library, which means it is always present.